# How to translate Materialize Datepicker in Angular

Tags: angular, datepicker, translation, materialize, pickadate

Using Datepicker (pickadate) from Materialize library in Angular 2 application. 
I came across problems translating its Month, Weekdays and buttons in the popup window. 
Are there some parameters I can pass it to translate it?

My Datepicker is initialized like this (using `angular2-materialize`):

```
<input #datepickerField materialize="pickadate"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are translation parameters you can pass it via `[materializeParams]` input.

```
<input #datepickerField 
      materialize="pickadate" 
      [materializeParams]=[
          {monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'May', ...]},
          {monthsFull: ['January', 'February', 'May', ...]},
          {weekdaysShort: ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', ...]},
          {weekdaysFull: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', ...]},
          {clear: 'Close button translation'},
          {today: 'Today button translation'},
          {close: 'Submit OK button translation'}
]>
```

Hope it helps.